# TTS - Text to Speech Synthesis System

Tags: text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I am trying to make a html page including TTS - Text to Speech Synthesis System feature. Please suggest me some online good demos.

Also please let me know if google is providing any api for TTS - Text to Speech Synthesis System.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Unofficial Google API and the limit is 100 characters

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=Hello+Sanket